# How to get Zebra Printer Name if I know the IP address in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, zebra-printers

I am using the Zebra printers. I am able to get the printers in the current network, but I am not able to get it's names using the IP.

I am following the below docs.
https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-13/ios/

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the NetworkDiscoverer class directed at that IP address. in the return data when the printer responds you will find the printer name.

For an example pull down the demo that is part of the SDK. You can build and run that to see how it works.